# bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xae8d250 error

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, dispatch-async

bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xae8d250: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

My Code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[self.navigationController pushViewController:aController animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `performSelectorinMainThread:`